# Multiple notifications with multiple action

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have multiple notifications, each notification has two buttons (`Start` and `Pause`) like the below picture and each notification belongs to a unique user.
Each notification has a unique notification ID based on each user name.
I use `pending intent` and `putExtra` to deal with action buttons but it does not work.
putExtra will send, `useName` is unique for each user:

```
intentPause.putExtra(userName,"pause");
intentResume.putExtra(userName,"start");
```

I think that the problem is I don't know which notification I am dealing with each time I click an action button so that BroadcastReceiver onReceive method which receives String from putExtra. How can I get String `userName` in `intentPause.putExtra(userName,"pause");` in order to put it in `String action = intent.getStringExtra(userName);`
Sorry for my bad English.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       
            String action = intent.getStringExtra(userName);//Dont know how to get UserName from PutExtra
            if (action.equals("resume")) {
                timerResume();
                Log.d("Action:", action);

            } else if (action.equals("pause")) {
                timerCancel();
                Log.d("Action:", action);

            }
       
    }
    public void timerResume(){
        MainActivity.timerMap.get(userName).countDownTimer.start();

        Log.d("Test resume:",userName);

    }

    public void timerCancel(){
        MainActivity.timerMap.get(userName).countDownTimer.cancel();
        Log.d("Test cancel:",userName);

    }
```

[image]

Based on the answer of @alexal1. I have tried but `getStringExtra` in `BroadCast Receiver` always return `NULL`

> Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver2">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tuan.timer.ACTION_PAUSE" />
            <action android:name="com.tuan.timer.ACTION_RESUME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

> NotificationReceiver2

```
public class NotificationReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_PAUSE= "com.tuan.timer.ACTION_PAUSE";
    public static final String ACTION_RESUME= "com.tuan.timer.ACTION_RESUME";
    public static final String EXTRA_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    String userName;
    String action;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

//getStringExtra return NULL
        Log.d ("myApplication", bundle2string(bundle) + " is a key in the bundle");
        Log.d ("get extra user name", intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME) );


        if(action != null){
            Log.d("Action: ",action );
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Action: ","is null" );
        }

    }
```

> MainActivity

```
intentPause=new Intent(this, notificationReceiver2.class);
intentPause.setAction(NotificationReceiver2.ACTION_PAUSE);
intentPause.putExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME,userName);
Log.d("Put Extra:",NotificationReceiver2.ACTION_PAUSE);
        pendingIntentPause=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,notificationId,this.intentPause,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        
 intentResume=new Intent(this, notificationReceiver2);
 intentResume.setAction(NotificationReceiver2.ACTION_RESUME);
   intentResume.putExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME,userName);
        Log.d("Put Extra:",NotificationReceiver2.ACTION_RESUME);
```

Comment: Finally, thank alexal1, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you don't use `putExtra()` correctly. It doesn't put two values, it puts one value by a key. So, you should build your `Intent`s like this:

```
String ACTION_PAUSE = "pause";
String EXTRA_USER_NAME = "user_name";
Intent intentPause = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
intentPause.setAction(ACTION_PAUSE); // we put button action in a specific field, not in extras
intentPause.putExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME, userName);
```

Then wrap this `Intent` with `PendingIntent` and attach to your notification:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntentPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentPause, 0);
```

In your BroadcastReceiver first check action type, and only then get data from extras:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(ACTION_PAUSE)) {
        timerResume();
        Log.d("Action:", action);
        String userName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME);
    }
    ...
}
```